Google test maximal size of test parameter array is too small
I am using Google's C++ testing framework (nuget package Microsoft.googletest.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.static.rt-dyn, version 1.8.1.7) and I am parametrizing tests. I have a problem with the array of parameters when it is too big : in a simple case with two parameter 2 and 96 like in the following :
INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(
    PricingTests,
    Bulk1,
    ::testing::Values(2,96));

there's no problem because we have
template <typename T1, typename T2>
internal::ValueArray2<T1, T2> Values(T1 v1, T2 v2) {
  return internal::ValueArray2<T1, T2>(v1, v2);
}

and
template <typename T1, typename T2>
class ValueArray2 {
 public:
  ValueArray2(T1 v1, T2 v2) : v1_(v1), v2_(v2) {}

  template <typename T>
  operator ParamGenerator<T>() const {
    const T array[] = {static_cast<T>(v1_), static_cast<T>(v2_)};
    return ValuesIn(array);
  }

  ValueArray2(const ValueArray2& other) : v1_(other.v1_), v2_(other.v2_) {}

 private:
  // No implementation - assignment is unsupported.
  void operator=(const ValueArray2& other);

  const T1 v1_;
  const T2 v2_;
};

in the framework allowing to handle an array of two paremeters. And Google was nice and implemented everything up to ValueArray50. But I have an array of more than 6000 parameters, each representing a different test cast that I have to test. I can I still make ::testing::Values is case of arrays with huge sizes ?

Nice story that you have realized the ValueArray limit. What is your question?

It was changed in v1.10.0 almost 5 years ago: New variadic implementation for gtest-param-test. You need to update GoogleTest.

I see you guessed right what my question was. ;) Thx. It is btw crazy to have so much lag in the latest google test nuget package with the last google test version.

Yes, I guessed it, but my guess could be wrong. You might be looking for an alternative solution. In this case an answer would be with using ValuesIn().

@EricFlorentNoube you can, and imho you should, still edit the quesiton to ask an actual question.

You can use a more official vcpkg install gtest instead of nuget with user packages.

By the way I am lucky to have a 64GB RAM laptop because compiling the project alone (with an array with 6000 integers) uses 50-55 GB of RAM ...
